# JOOQ insert into select syntax with specified columns

Tags: java, sql, select, insert, jooq

Can JOOQ do 'insert into select' syntax for specified columns? I run several different tries..

The Tables:

table1 (Expected insert)

```
id   column1   column2    column3 ...  timestamp
1    John      Leo        null         2012/1/28 23:32:23    (Expected insert)
```

table2

```
id   col1   col2   col3  
101  John   xxx    xxx     (from table2.col1)
102  xxx    xxx    xxx
```

table3

```
id   col1   col2   col3  
101  xxx    Leo    xxx     (from table3.col2)
102  xxx    xxx    xxx
```

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 ( column1, column2 )
SELECT  table2.col1, table3.col2
FROM table2 join table3 t3 on table2.id = table3.id 
where table2.id = 101;
```

JOOQ code:

```java
create.insertInto(table1, column1, column2 )
      .values( create.select( table2.col1, table3.col2 )
                     .from(table2)
                     .join(table3)
                     .on( table12.id.equal(table3.id) )
                     .where( table2.id.equal(101) ))
     .execute(); //.getSQL();
```

JOOQ show error message:

```
The number of values must match the number of fields
```

Anyone know what problem I make and how I can fix my JOOQ code.
thanks, Pay.

Reference: 
[Example: INSERT SELECT syntax support](http://www.jooq.org/manual/JOOQ/Query/)

Answer (score 10):

You're using the `INSERT .. VALUES` syntax, instead of the `INSERT .. SELECT` syntax. Your subquery provides values `column1` but you don't provide any value for `column2`. What you want to do is described further down in the manual at "Example: INSERT SELECT syntax support". In your case, this would read (jOOQ 2.x syntax, no longer available in jOOQ 3.x):

```
create.insertInto(table1, 
create.select( table2.col1, table3.col2 )
      .from(table2)
      .join(table3)
      .on( table12.id.equal(table3.id) )
      .where( table2.id.equal(101) ))
      .execute(); //.getSQL();
```

Or with a custom projection (jOOQ 3.x syntax):

```
create.insertInto(table1, column1, column2)
      .select(create.select(...))
      .execute();
```

Comment: The value for column2 is provided from 'table3.col2'

Comment: my issue is when there are more than 2 columns at table1, how can I use specified columns for table1.

Comment: the example of INSERT SELECT is for copy to all columns values.

Comment: @payliu: You're right. I later realised that what you want to do is currently not possible. The next version of jOOQ will ship with [this feature implemented](https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/jooq/ticket/1069)

Comment: Dear @Lukas, Got it, many thanks. my temp solution is use sub-select by JOOQ to getSql and concat to an insert syntax by self. It's double effort to me. This function is much convenient and useful. Thanks again.Got it, many thanks. my temp solution is use sub-select by JOOQ to getSql and concat to an insert syntax by self. It's double effort to me. This function is much convenient and useful. Thanks again.

Comment: @payliu: jOOQ 2.0.3 was released on Jan 29, so you should be able to use the syntax you needed. Cheers, Lukas

Comment: Dear @Lukas, 
this custom projection syntax is working, very thanks!!

Comment: @Lukas, I am trying to use the 1st format you recommended, but it seems it doesn't work with the current Jooq. There's only insertInto(Table<R> into, Collection<? extends Field<?>> fields), but I would need SelectFinalStep as the 2nd parameter to insertInto

Comment: @Gavriel: Thanks for pointing that out. That particular method was deprecated in jOOQ 2.x. Only the latter is now supported in jOOQ 3.x. I'll update my (outdated) answer

Comment: :( I would be happier with that function returning...

So let's try it the other way:
getDSLContext().insertInto(table).select(select); so far it seems to be ok, but I'd like to continue with: .onDuplicateKeyUpdate().set(updateMap); How would that be possible?

Comment: @Gavriel: Unfortunately, there is an API flaw in that area. That's currently not possible: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2529

Comment: ok, 3rd try: getDSLContext().insertInto(table2).select(getDSLContext().select(table1.field1).from(table1)).getSQL() creates this: "insert into table2 () select table1.field1 from table1" THe problem is with the "()" after the table name...

Comment: @Gavriel: Sigh, this doesn't seem to be your lucky jOOQ day :-/. Thanks for reporting. I've registered an high-priority issue for this case: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2995